# CloudFormation - Using Fn::If Inside Alarm Annotations

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a CloudFormation dashboard where I link/reference alarms using Alarm Annotations.

The names/ARNs of these alarms differ based on a condition. I want to a include a simple condition using the Fn::If intrinsic condition as below:

I have tried the following:

```
"properties": {
  "annotations": {
    "alarms": [
      {'Fn::If': ["<condition>", "<value_if_true>", "<value_if_false>"]}
    ]
  }
}
```

This gives me an error. I want to include a simple if condition.
Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Can you paste full template code of your dashboard. Also what error exactly are you getting?

Comment: I am using Jinja as the templating engine to generate these .yml files and I get a expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>' at the line where Fn::If is called.

Comment: Try with double quotes: `"Fn::If"`. Single quotes are not json complaint.

Comment: Does it provide any error message?

Comment: Added the error message in my previous comment. 

Error Message - The metric widget should have specified a region and a data source or an alarm annotation

Comment: I can post the answer to the orgial issue reported. Its difficult to speculate on the new issue, based on comments. I would suggest making new question with new details, template code, error messages. The new issue does not seem to be related to the problems with quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the commends, the issue reported was caused by the use of **single quotes** in `'Fn::If'`.

The solution was to use **double quotes**, as single quotes are not json complient: `"Fn::If"`.